# how to configure iad adds adwhirl for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have configure adwhirl in my app but add's are not displayed is there any configuration needed in apple account for iad ? if needed any settings for iad in apple account then please guide me and also tell me how to configure that settings in adwhirl.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5350/how-to-integrate-adwhirl-into-a-cocos2d-game) to integrate adwhirl for iad and other ads.

Add iad account on adwhirl account of yours by loging to [adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/)

Download latest AdwhirlAPI and add to your project. Refer [Api](https://code.google.com/p/adwhirl-with-iad/downloads/detail?name=AdWhirl_pro.zip&can=2&q=) and [setup](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html) links

In .h of  yourcontroller

```
@interface yourController : <AdWhirlDelegate>
```

Now Do following things in .m file where u wnat adwhirl:

1) DefineAdwhirlKey

```
  #define kSampleAppKey @"your adwhirl key"
```

2)  Add code in viewDidLoad

```
  AdWhirlView *awView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
  [awView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,326,320,50)];//set your frame
  [awView setDelegate:self];
  [self.view addSubview:awView];
```

3) Add AdwhirlDelegate methods

```
   - (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey
  {
    return kSampleAppKey;
  }

  - (UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView
 {
   return self;
 }
```

Comment: i referred that example but configuring whole process then also not working in my project if passing the same adwhirl key in other example it works, we have to configure banner for iad ????

Comment: it defines where u want to place your ad in view

Answer (score 0):

To use AdWhirl in ur application , you need to register here :

https://www.adwhirl.com/home/register

From here you'll get a unique key.Download the API for Adwhirl and then integrate the key to it.The Adwhirl manages iAd, admob etc. percentage wise.When one fails to load , the adwhirl loads the another.

you can refer this link also :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5350/how-to-integrate-adwhirl-into-a-cocos2d-game

Comment: i referred that example but configuring whole process then also not working in my project if passing the same adwhirl key in other example it works, we have to configure banner for iad ????

Comment: Did u followed the whole process ??

Make sure You defined your key here properly






`- (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey {`
    `return @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the new Admob mediation instead as I believe adwhirl will soon become unsupported as they are concentrating on AdMob now (both owned by google).

Comment: as per the client requirement i have to integrate iad not admob so need that integration

Comment: Admob mediation is basically the same as adwhirl. It's mediation for many ad networks including iAd. If you only need iAd then you'd be better implimenting it on it's own.